# Manual reverse order in Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, reverse

Hello people of StackOverflow!
I have used the searrch option, I've found some related answers but none of them explained why this particular method of reverse ordering of an array in Java doesn't work:

```
class ReverseOrder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int y[] = x;

        int i, j;
        for(i = 0, j = x.length - 1; i < x.length; i++, j--)
        {
            y[i] = x[j];
        }

        for(int b = 0; b < x.length; b++)
        {
            System.out.println("Inverse order is: " + y[b]);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the result 5,4,3,4,5 instead of 5,4,3,2,1??? It drives me absolutely insane and makes no sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of this:
int y[] = x

y and x are now references to the same array.  You should make sure you initialize y as a new array.

Comment: Yeah, you need to do int y[] = new int[x.length];

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely solved the problem. However I have an extra question - should I do it this way now?

int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int y[] = new int[5];
y = x.clone();

Or perhaps there is faster and more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: it is enough to replace int y[] = x with int y[] = new int [x.lengt], this assures y is initialized and has enough capacity to hold the x content. Y is filled with values in the loop  you are filling y in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ReverseOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int y[] = new int[5]; // or you could use [x.length]
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0, j = x.length - 1; i < x.length; i++, j--)
        {
            y[i] = x[j];
        }

        for(int b = 0; b < x.length; b++)
        {
            System.out.println("Inverse order is: " + y[b]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, basically what was explained above, with the x.length ,I did not see the answer before i posted

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You people are so quick to answer and help! I wish I could give you all up and mark everyone's answer as accepted! But I just registered :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int y[] = x;
```

Makes y refer to the same data as x.

```
y[i] = x[j];
```

you are also modifying the input array x.

You want y to be totally independent:

```
int y[] = new int[x.length];
```

instead.

Comment: Oh thank you too! So is that more efficient way than this one:

int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int y[] = new int[x.length];
y = x.clone();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reverse the order of array elements in place (that is, modify the array `x` directly), you can iterate halfway through the array, swapping elements:

```
final int last = x.length - 1;
final int n_2 = x.length / 2; // round down for odd lengths
for (int i = 0; i < n_2; ++i) {
    int tmp = x[i];
    x[i] = x[last - i];
    x[last - i] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've heard of that method, but I was just plain confused and wanted to first clarify the whole case before continuing with studying Java :)